# How to create ANSI36 and ANSI37 hatch using css

Tags: css

I would like to create two hatched backgrounds using css that look like this (ANSI36 and ANSI37):

[image: ANSI36]

[image: ANSI37]

I thought this would work using repeating-linear-gradients because ANSI31 (see below) is possible using css but I couldn't figure out how. Be aware that I can't use an svg-pattern because the ANSI36 has to be asigned to the background property of an html-button. In addition, I don't want to use predefined images because I'd like to configure the color of the hatches.

[image: ANSI31]

CSS-code for ANSI31:

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image:
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      -45deg,
      transparent 0 10px,
      black 10px 20px
    );
}
```

I know the size of the background and it is always the same. Is there any other way to draw this kind of pattern dynamically using css or js?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle or similar of what you have tried so far? Also your images are not working.

Comment: Since that is a simple repeated image you could use a simple background image on repeat to create it. Are you looking for a pure CSS without using a background image?

Comment: Image are working for me. I don't know what the problem is.
I would like to be able to choose the color of the hatch. That's why I would rather use css than a background image

Comment: @Andrew The images not working seems to be a temporary imgur glitch and not OP’s fault.

Comment: I can see them now

Comment: Use **multiple** backgrounds - it's allowed - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/mZLRQm

Comment: Ok thanks. What about ANSI36?

Comment: Oh btw. The size of the background is fixed and always the same. If there is another way of creating something that looks like these patterns dynamically using js or css, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply generate `ANSI36` CSS code by using [**patternify**](http://www.patternify.com/).

```css
body {
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAPUlEQVQoU43PQQoAMAgDweT/j7ZYUGoRo+dhicTujAtnAKjgRR6bYCIFy6quWEqh1casvrAt/cURxTMSOTyKNQgKOBqKWwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
) repeat;
}
```

Comment: Since I'd like to add rotated and colored patterns this will not work because of the big amount of images I'd need